# How can i change images on swipe?

Tags: android, imageview, swipe

i have 25 pictures in my project
i have a button in first activity and when click this button i want my app show the first pic of 25 and then i want swipe on mobile left to right or right to left and change my pics 
help me please
its my first experience in android

this code isnt important :D

```
package com.example.start;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
{
    private LinearLayout main;
    private TextView viewA;
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);

        main = new LinearLayout(this);     
        main.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        main.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320,480));

        viewA = new TextView(this);     
        viewA.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        viewA.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        viewA.setTextSize(16);
        viewA.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320,80));

        main.addView(viewA);
        setContentView(main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
    {
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        viewA.setText("-" + "DOWN" + "-");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        viewA.setText("-" + "FLING" + "-");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        viewA.setText("-" + "LONG PRESS" + "-");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        viewA.setText("-" + "SCROLL" + "-");
        return true;
    }       

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        viewA.setText("-" + "SHOW PRESS" + "-");
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)    
    {
        viewA.setText("-" + "SINGLE TAP UP" + "-");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to imlemente gesture functionnailies like that. Here I would tell you to use a ViewPager like the gallery app.

There is a really sample example [here](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/) with a video, so you can see how you can swipe from left to right.

Comment: can you say your answer with more detail ?
where can i find this code ?